# Android app doesn't show up on tablet marketplace

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have been reading many questions on stackoverflow and I can't quite figure this problem out. I have an app that has a call feature but I still want tablets to access it. The app works on tablets if I manually install it via USB but it will not show up on the market place. I know that there are other questions regarding this issue but I am also asking if there are any other permissions I have that will not work on tablets.

Here is my manifest..

```xml
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <!-- End of copy. -->
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I originally just had `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`

But I recently added..

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Will this solve the problem of the tablet not being able to make calls and have it listed on the tablet marketplace?

Also, are there any other permissions that I have listed that I need to add `android:required="false"` to?

Also, this is how I am calling in the code...

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + markPhone));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to call using `ACTION_DIAL` not `ACTION_CALL`:

```
try {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
   startActivity( intent );
} catch ( Exception e ) {
   // no dialer activity found...
}
```

then you can completely remove these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

from your Manifest, as your app is no longer need them.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I will try it out. But are there any other permissions that will make the app not show up to tablets on the market place?

Comment: what is the difference of action_dial and action_call?